# Confidentiality on quip pages/spreadsheets

Tags: quip, liveapps

Quip is used for participant's registration regarding employee health program.
Would it be possible to create a confidential environment which only allows a few people to view the whole content of a document?

e.g. a table shows date/time and appointment slots to all
but only the quip creator and approved people can view the entered employee information?
Employees would only see blocked or vacant cells?

Would this be possible or is this feature already available?

Thanks Nicola

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid Quip doesn't allow for different users to see different portions of a document, however you can mirror a portion of a document into another one. The idea is that you can create an "internal" document, and an "external" document which only shows parts of the internal one.

Check out Live Paste on how to do so: https://quip.com/blog/sync-content-with-Live-Paste